# The significance of parenthesis in JS

Tags: javascript

Consider this code:

```
var Student = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Student(firstName="ajith", middleInitial, lastName="k") {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
    return Student;
}()); //1.Removing the outer parenthesis also works!!! help

function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}

var user = new Student;//2.here new Student() and new Student both work!!help
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

Why do parentheses stop mattering near those two comments? By the way, the above code was generated by typescript compiler.

Comment: Regarding #1, why are you surprised? Those parentheses don't play any role. Maybe you where thinking of something like `var a = (function () {})();`

Comment: What do you mean by stopped mattering? If you're comparing to an IIFE, it's because the parser know that it will be an expression so it doesn't need the parens, contrary to IIFE where it could be confused with a function declaration

Comment: The entire IIFE is wrapped in an extra set of parenthesis.  It's the difference between `x` and `(x)`.

Comment: *"1.Removing the outer paranthesis also works!"* -- it wasn't always like this. Years ago, the JavaScript interpreters used to be confused about the programmer's intention (and reported error) when those parenthesis were missing.

Comment: @Amy Will C++ tolerate such extra paranthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `(function() {...}())` defines an anonymous function and calls it. You can remove the outer parenthesis because `function() {...}()` still does the same thing. The only place this wouldn't work is if JavaScript expects a statement (the `function` keyword would expect a function declaration, which requires a name after this). Since this is an assignment, the function call is fine.
- JavaScript allows you to call constructors without parenthesis in some contexts, so `new Foo()` and `new Foo` are the same.

Comment: You misread the IIFE (easy to do).  It's `(function() { .... }())`.  The closing parenthesis comes after the IIFE is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the outer parentheses are not needed because the `function` keyword can only begin a function instantiation expression. Parentheses are only necessary to make the parser understand that you want an expression and not a function declaration *statement*.

The common use of parentheses therefore is in statements like this:

```
(function() {
  // do something
})();
```

Without that initial `(`, the `function` keyword would be taken by the parser as the beginning of a function declaration statement, which would mean that the function could not be immediately invoked via the `()` at the end; function declaration syntax does not allow that.

The second case is unrelated. When calling a constructor via `new`, when no arguments are passed the parentheses are optional.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass parameters, then use it, if not - write shortly, but there is one more difference:

```
new Date.getTime() // won't work.
new Date().getTime() // will work.
(new Date).getTime() // will work
```